# Why templates declared in the struct on the header dont violate ODR and specialization does?

Tags: c++, templates, one-definition-rule

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    template<typename T> bool isImplemented()
    {
                std::cout << "Not Implemented" << std::endl;
                return false;
    }
};

template<> inline bool A::isImplemented<int>()
{
    std::cout << "int Implemented" << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

I can understand why the template specialization needs the inline, in order to prevent the ODR to be violated the inline will merge the translation table avoiding a conflict.

But, why I don`t need an inline on the isImplemented inside the struct A?
Maybe that question can be extended to, why if the method is declared inside the struct/class on the header it does not need the inline?
As I can understand, it would create the symbols on every object file (.o) that it is called, violating the ODR, why that does not happen?

Comment: Anything with a template parameter is essentially implicitly `inline`.

Comment: The template specialization is a function. The template is a template. Templates aren't functions, and vice versa. Templates follow different rules.

Comment: @KerrekSB that actually helps a LOT, thanks. I was having issues trying to understand why I only need that on specializations. I imagine that this is the same rule applied when you declare friend operators and you need to use inline in order to prevent the violation on the ODR, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need it for two reasons:

- Every function defined within the definition of the class is implicit `inline`.
- A template doesn't need `inline` keyword. Remember, your original function is a template, while specialization is not.

Answer (score 1):

The point to highlight here is that `template<typename T> bool isImplemented()` *IS NOT a function*.
It is a template to a function and will only exist (as code) once specialized, like you did with `template<> inline bool A::isImplemented<int>()`.

The `inline` here is not mandatory. Program compiles and runs perfectly without it.

Strangely your `struct A` does not depend on any template parameter neither `isImplemented()` method so I am still trying to figure out your intention.

A simple usage of your functions might look like this:

```
int  main( )
{
    A a;

    a.isImplemented< int >( );
    a.isImplemented< double >( );
}
```

And the output:

```
int Implemented
Not Implemented
```

And basically you are able to tell wich specializations you have explicitly implemented from the generic ones. Is it what you need?

**EDIT:**

Given the comment on my answer, I believe the original question is nicely answered here:

- [Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052579/explicit-specialization-in-non-namespace-scope)
- [C++ syntax for explicit specialization of a template function in a template class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097811/c-syntax-for-explicit-specialization-of-a-template-function-in-a-template-clas)

Comment: Actually, this is a code that I wrote to understand the inline and the ODR. That is why it is like that. It comes from a problem that I had long time ago trying to specialize something based on the return type.